# Unable to clear a beginning of a line by C-u in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I run the following command in Emacs unsuccessfully

```
C-u
```

**How can you clear the beginning of a line in Emacs?**

Comment: What do you mean by the "beginning" of a line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the mark, go to the beginning, kill till mark:

```
C-Spc C-a C-w
```

Comment: `C-0 C-k` is less typing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818425/unable-to-clear-a-beginning-of-a-line-by-c-u-in-emacs/1580519#1580519

Answer (score 13):

You can also accomplish this by using a prefix arg for kill-ine (usually C-k). From the Emacs help (C-h k C-k):

> With zero argument, kills the text before point on the current line.

So, you can do

```
C-u 0 C-k
```

or even better

```
C-0 C-k
```

Comment: `C-0 C-k` may not work in terminal-mode Emacs, probably due to the `C-0` not being passed to Emacs correctly via the terminal emulator. `M-0 C-k` mentioned in another answer works in terminal-mode Emacs.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
M-0 C-k
```

[Delete from beginning of line to point](http://www.columbia.edu/acis/publications/emacs.html)

Comment: `C-0 C-k` seems more sensible, to avoid changing modifier keys.

Answer (score 6):

C-u works in Bash "Emacs Mode", but not actually in Emacs. Here's what I usually do:

```
C-a C-k
```

But this is really only good if you want to kill the *whole* line.  Svante's advice will clear from the beginning of the line to where your cursor was, as you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, where you read about <kbd>C-u</kbd>, but it is bound to the [universal argument](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html) in Emacs.

If you want to kill the whole line, call `kill-whole-line` which is bound <kbd>C-S-backspace</kbd>. No matter at what column is the cursor, it will kill the whole line from beginning to end.

Comment: Yes. Maybe your terminal does not support that sequence but you can always type `M-x kill-whole-line` or set your own shortcut with `(global-set-key [C-S-backspace] 'kill-whole-line)`.

Comment: `*C-u* 0 C-k` kills to beginning of line.

Answer (score 2):

I have a small function bound to a key-chord:

```
(defun kill-start-of-line ()
  "kill from point to start of line"
  (interactive)
  (kill-line 0))

(define-key global-map "\M-#" 'kill-start-of-line)
```

M-# is usually Alt-Shift-3, not a new DotNet language

I'm sure I saw this somewhere else, but didn't save the original reference.

Comment: This may be the original? http://stray-notes.blogspot.com/2010/03/emacs-delete-to-start-of-line_22.html